Kubernetes - oauth2-proxy - Keycloak OIDC - OAuth2CodeParser error - CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR code already used for userSession and client
I installed on Kubernetes (OpenShift) an application (application A) which is using OAuth authentication.
The authentication is done server-side -  the backend application is making the handshake with a KeyCloak instance (KeyCloak-01) with a specific client_id_A and client_secret_A from realm [realm01].
In the same Kubernetes cluster namespace I installed another application (application B) where I used for authentication the [oauth2-proxy] reverse proxy with [keycloak-oidc] provider setup by using with a specific client_id_B and client_secret_B from the same realm [realm01] of the same KeyCloak instance (KeyCloak-01).
Both applications have authentication configured to be “cookie-based” and not “JWT token-based”.
The desired behavior is the single-sing-on one: once authenticated in one application to be automatically authenticated in the other one – since both application are using client_id’s from the same KeyCloak realm instance.
The authentication flow for both applications works fine if they are opened in different browser instances.
If both applications are opened in the same browser instance (different tabs) the behavior is not the desired one.
If application A is opened first, user_01 is successfully authenticated. If same user [user-01] tries to access application B in the same browser instance the result is 500 ingress error code issued due to 400 status code received from [oauth2-proxy/auth] service endpoint.
If application B (under oauth2-proxy reverse proxy) is opened first, user_01 is successfully authenticated. If the same user [user-01] tries to access application A in the same browser instance, he is redirected to login page where he can successfully login. But from that moment on the application B is no longer working – same error as above - 500 ingress error code issued due to 400 status code received from [oauth2-proxy/auth] service endpoint.
Errors from oauth2-proxy container logs:
169.254.169.5 - - [17/Apr/2024:10:40:41 +0000] "GET /[oauth-app-name]/auth HTTP/1.1" 400 628 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 1117 0.001 [] [] - - - - 1dd96bfdb357d7d1292553dc7a8ad520
2024/04/17 10:40:41 [error] 2617#2617: *14681947 auth request unexpected status: 400 while sending to client, client: 100.64.0.3, server: some-host.com, request: "GET /[app-name-base-path]/[route-value] / HTTP/2.0", host: "some-host.com"

Errors from KeyCloak container logs:
12:45:55,616 WARN  [org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.utils.OAuth2CodeParser] (default task-133) Code '[code-guid]' already used for userSession '[user-session-guid]' and client '[client-guid]'.
12:45:55,616 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-133) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId= realm01, clientId= client_id_B, userId=null, ipAddress=10.128.3.124, error=invalid_code, grant_type=authorization_code, code_id=[user-session-guid], client_auth_method=client-secret

When application A redirect user to KeyCloak login page the query params looks like this:
client_id= client_id_A
redirect_uri=…./ signin-oidc
response_type=code
scope= openid profile
code_challenge=….sfgreggr….
code_challenge_method= S256
response_mode= form_post
nonce=…dfsdf…
acr_values = some_guid
ui_locales= en-us
state=….dfgdrg…
x-client-SKU=some-value
x-client-ver=some-version

When application B redirect user to KeyCloak login page the query params looks like this:
client_id= client_id_B
redirect_uri=…./ signin-oidc
response_type=code
scope= openid+email+profile
state=….xxxxvvdrg…

Please guide me to identify solution for the followings:

How could I enable the debug verbose logging for auth2-proxy container (used for application B) in order to get details from the /auth endpoint error?
I tried different environment variables values but the auth2-proxy container logs doesn’t include response details about calls performed against of KeyCloak instance
What settings from auth2-proxy container (used for application B) are wrong/mismatched?
I suppose the issue is that the authentication settings from application A and B are not “aligned”.

